# Arraylist java program

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Help in writing a program using the array list which stores the values of name, address, phone number, date and time (for each customer) and later I need to retrieve the specific information like all the customer's name on a specified date. any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
public class Details {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        String s;
        s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT NAME");
        String name = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT ADDRESS");
        String add = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT CONTACT PHONE NUMBER");
        String pnum = br.readLine();
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("name");
        list.add("add");
        list.add("pnum");
        list.add("food");
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a website to generate code for you. Show us what you got, ask specific questions about the things you do not understand (after looking up the question on Google/Stackoverflow).

Comment: public class Details
{
public static void main(String args[])
throws IOException
{
InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(rdr);
String s;
s = br.readLine();
System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT NAME");
String name= br.readLine();
System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT ADDRESS"); 
String add= br.readLine(); 
System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER CLIENT CONTACT PHONE NUMBER"); 
String pnum= br.readLine();    
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("name");
list.add("add");
list.add("pnum");
list.add("food");

}
}

Comment: Update your question with the code, indented 4 spaces. Difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: i accepted the data dynamically from user and added to array list but can i add all the details in the same index like the index 0 contains all info of a particular customer

Comment: after creating a array list --> List list = new ArrayList() i added the details of name, address pnum and food for only one customer like list.add ("name") is there a way i can add name, address, pnum, food in the index zero of arraylist but not in different indexes

Answer (score 3):

Create a class `Customer` like this -

```
public class Customer{
   private String name; 
   private String address;
   private String phoneNumber;
   private Date date;

  public Customer(name, address, phoneNumber, date){

     this.name = name;
     this.address = address;
     this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
     this.date = date;
  }

   //getters and setters method

}
```

After that you create an ArrayList of Customer like this -

```
List<Customer> `customerList` = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

Now create an object/instance of `Customer` like this -

```
Customer aCustomer = new Customer("ranjit", "someAddress", "023-859 74", new Date() );
```

Then add the `Customer` object/instance `aCustomer` to `ArrayList` of `Customer` - `customerList` like this:

```
customerList.add(aCustomer);
```

In the given way you can more easily handle a Customer. Now you have a single entity containing all the customer attributes (name, address, phoneNumber etc). So you don't need store all the attributes/property in separate `ArrayList`

Comment: System.out.println("Enter the appointment ID to see the full details :");
   int y=in.nextInt();
   int r;
   for(r=0;r<count;r++)
   {
    if(all.get(r).getID()==y)
    {
     all.get(r).display();
    }
   }i am using this code to retrieve the full details that have been entered using the get statement and display function. this is a small part of my program. i was wondering is there any other way to do it